# DNS and virtual hosting in Amazon Lightsail issue

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server, amazon-web-services, vps

I have an issue with Amazon lightsail VPS and virtual hosting, and here is the details:

**domain nameservers already set in godaddy.**

**DNS records on amazon lightsail:**

[image: dns-recoreds]

**/etc/hosts:**

```
35.157.225.38 arabsooq.me
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available** and it's enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@arabsooq.me
    ServerName arabsooq.me
    ServerAlias www.arabsooq.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/arabsooq.me/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**and already I have index.html file in this folder:**

```
/var/www/arabsooq.me/public_html
```

**The problem:**
The ip is working but the domain name is not, even if you ping on it!

[35.157.225.38](http://35.157.225.38)

[arabsooq.me](http://arabsooq.me)

Answer (score 1):

The site seems to be working from my home. Without any changes I get the following:
[image: screenshot]

You might be running into DNS caching issues. The problem could resolve itself in 24 hours as the caches will probably have expired by then.

Comment: Thanks very much, is it possible to be an issue from my internet provider, because it's happens from long time! @mtak